# About a complex sequence and complex logarithms

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, logarithms, complex-dynamics

#### Intro

I am studying complex logarithms and particularly the following sequence $(z_n)$ defined by:
$$z_0 \in \mathbb{C} \\
\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, z_{n+1} = \log_{\mathrm{i}} z_n$$
It involves:
$ z_0 \not =  {^{p}i}$ with $p \in \mathbb{N}$ i.e. $ z_0 \not = 0, 1, \mathrm{i}, \mathrm{i}^\mathrm{i}, ...$
So that we cannot have a $\log_{\mathrm{i}}(0)$ after a few iterations.
We could rewrite the sequence as follows:
$$ z_{n+1} = \frac{\log z_n}{\log \mathrm{\mathrm{i}}} \\
z_{n+1} = \frac{2\log z_n}{\mathrm{i}\pi}$$
Where $\log z$ is the principal value – since $\log z$ is multiple-valued – defined by:
$$\log z = \log |z| + \mathrm{i}\arg z, -\pi < \arg z \leq \pi$$

#### Observations

So I have computed all this in Python to get more information about how this sequence behaves then plotted it.
Here is what I have noticed so far. 
Sometimes the sequence simply converges (e.g. when $z_0 = -2-5\mathrm{i}, z_0 = 5-100\mathrm{i}, z_0 = 8$) to always the same value which is approximatively $-1.8617 - 0.4108\mathrm{i}$ and it looks like this when plotted:
[image]

(Note that $z_0$ is not plotted. And there is actually a million points on this graph.)

But sometimes it will diverge and after a few iterations it will alternate between 3 values which are also always the same regardless of $z_0$ (e.g. when $z_0=2+5\mathrm{i}, z_0=3\mathrm{i}$):
[image]

#### Some questions

How to prove that this sequence sometimes converges? 
How could we determine when the sequence will converge or diverge depending on $z_0$?

### Update

To expand on what @Cesareo said in response, let's assume we have :
$$ \lim_{n \to +\infty} z_n = w $$
It means we should have:
$$
w = \log_\mathrm{i} w \\
w = \frac{2\log w}{\mathrm{i}\pi} \\
\log w \times w^{-1} = \frac{\mathrm{i}\pi}{2} \\
\log w \times e^{-\log w} = \frac{\mathrm{i}\pi}{2} \\
- \log w \times e^{-\log w} = - \frac{\mathrm{i}\pi}{2} \\
- \log w = \mathrm{W}(- \frac{\mathrm{i}\pi}{2}) \\
w = e^{-\mathrm{W}(- \frac{\mathrm{i}\pi}{2})} \\
w = -\frac{2}{\mathrm{i}\pi}\mathrm{W}(- \frac{\mathrm{i}\pi}{2}) \\
w = \frac{2\mathrm{i}}{\pi}\mathrm{W}(- \frac{\mathrm{i}\pi}{2})$$
If we take the branch one of Lambert W function :
$$w \approx -1.8617 - 0.4108\mathrm{i}$$

Guys, please. It's been eleven months.

Comment: Let $f(z) = \log_i(z)$. Then the equation $f^{(3)}(z)=f(f(f(z)))=z$ has $5$ solutions $r_1,r_2,r_3,r_4,r_5$ and we have $f(r_1)=r_2, f(r_2)=r_3, f(r_3)=r_1, f(r_4)=r_4, f(r_5)=r_5$. This show that the complexity of the dynamic system will be high. And this comes only from considering $f^{(3)}(z)=z$.  So when you write "Guys, please. It's been eleven months." what are you expecting? To describe completely the dynamic of the function? Do you have any reason to believe this is feasible?

Answer (score 1):

Solving $$z=\log_i z$$ we have

$$
z=\frac{2 i W_1\left(-\frac{i \pi }{2}\right)}{\pi } = -1.8617430750131605 - 0.4107999688363923 i
$$

where $W_k$ represents the Product Log $k$-branch.

NOTE

The convergence can be attained from the dotted external region as shown in the following plots.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but this only answers my first question, why is not the sequence always converging?

Comment: The sequence converges for any initial point $z= x + i y$ such that $|z|\gt 1$ and $x < 0, y < 0$.

Comment: As I said, it converges on the conditions given, but not only on those conditions: it can converge also under other conditions .

Comment: How can we determine what these other conditions actually are?